# my user defined function with apply-->lambdas keeps producing "ValueError: The truth value of a series is ambiguous"

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda, apply

I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

I have two data frames, one containing 100+ columns and 54k cases, and a second dataframe that is summarizing information from the full dataset, grouped by a column called "countyName" (which has 66 unique values).

The function that i'm trying to create tests columns, grouped by 'countyName', and return -777 if all of the values for that column-county are -777, and if not, return the original value.

this is the code:

```
def change777s(report, df):
    list777 = list(df.columns[(df == -777).any()])
    report[list777]=df.groupby('countyName')[list777].agg(lambda x: -777 if x.all()==-777 else x)
    return report

df2_first=change777s(df2_first, first)
```

but i keep getting:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

or entirely incorrect results.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Note the difference between `x.all()==-777` and `(x==-777).all()`

Comment: i tried both of these and still got the same ValueError.